# Airflow 2.4 Google OAuth - Error authorizing OAuth access token: mismatch state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response

Tags: airflow, google-oauth, airflow-2.x

This seems to be an issue that's happening to many but I haven't found an answer yet!

We're trying to get google oauth working for Airflow 2.4.2. but I keep seeing the following error:

> ```
> Error authorizing OAuth access token: misma[REDACTED]: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response
> ```

My webserver_config.py file looks like this:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
import os
import logging

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True  # Checks roles on every login
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True  # allow users who are not already in the FAB DB to register
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"

#CSRF_ENABLED = True
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "Viewer": ["Viewer"],
    "Admin": ["Admin"],
}


OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "google",
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "whitelist": ['@blahblah.com'],
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": os.getenv("AIRFLOW_GCP_CLIENT_ID"),
            "client_secret": os.getenv("AIRFLOW_GCP_CLIENT_SECRET"),
            "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
            "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "request_token_url": None
        },
    },
]
```

to the config file I've also added:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True

auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.google_auth
```